# Do you have to store your products in Stripe to process payment

Tags: stripe-payments

I'm building a new web application, and we have a system that manages our products already. Does Stripe require the products to be in their system in order to be able to handle the payment processing? I don't see a clear answer to this via their docs, so I'm unsure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. As part of the API request you make to stripe to process your clients payment, you need to pass some basic info about price, currency, etc.

The ***price*** you can simply retrieve from your DB, or pass as a variable from the FE.

The ***token*** is what is passed in from the FE, and includes the clients payment info.

So no need to store your products with stripe.

```js
function createCharge(token, amount) {
     return stripe.charges.create({
         amount: amount * 100,
         currency: 'usd',
         source: token,
         description: "..."
     })
}
```

Comment: as a quick add on, at this point in time Charges are the legacy way of creating payments, and anyone new to Stripe should be using PaymentIntents.